# Installing Centos 6 using virt-install over SSH with no graphics - beginner

Tags: centos, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, centos6

I have a Centos 6 box with virtualised CPUs that is ready for installing a virtual OSs.  I am installing remotely over SSH and my Centos 6 box has no GUI (no GNOME etc) so it's purely command line.  The following command is starts of the installation just fine:

```
virt-install --nographics --name kvm3 --ram 768 --disk path=/home/chris/KVM/kvm3.img,size=12 --accelerate -c /home/chris/CentOS-6.2-x86_64-minimal.iso
```

I then get the following standard screen for Centos installation:

```
          +----------------------------------------------------------+
          |                  Welcome to CentOS 6.2!                  |
          |----------------------------------------------------------|
          | Install or upgrade an existing system                    |
          | Install system with basic video driver                   |
          | Rescue installed system                                  |
          | Boot from local drive                                    |
          | Memory test                                              |
          |                                                          |
          |                                                          |
          |                                                          |
          |                                                          |
          |                                                          |
          |                                                          |
          |                                                          |
          +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

and I hit Enter and get:

```
Loading vmlinuz......
Loading initrd.img................................ready.
Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok
```

then a load of whitespace and then this:

```
?
```

which is pretty uninformative.  My guess was that it was trying to load the GUI installation or something?  I have tried the `--nographics` option though.

Any ideas?  Many thanks :).

Comment: Have you tried hitting Tab instead of Enter and adding " text" then hitting enter? That's how I've entered text mode for previous 6.x versions in the past. Not sure if it will work for this.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is telling Anaconda (the installer) that your are doing a serial port install.  Add the keywords "serial console=ttyS0,57600" to your install line ("console" is for the kernel, and "serial" is picked up by Anaconda).